# Passing $key of FirebaseObjectObservable into function

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am new to Angular2 integration with Firebase so please forgive my naivety.

I'm using the AngularFire2 plugin to connect with my Firebase db and have been following their [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md) docs as such.

Up until now when I retrieve a `FirebaseObjectObservable`, I display it in my HTML using the `async` pipe described in the docs:

> To get the object in realtime, create an object binding as a property of your component or service. Then in your template, you can use the async pipe to unwrap the binding.

**HTML**:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let member of _tripMembers">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img src="{{ (member | async)?.photoUrl }}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>{{ (member | async)?.firstName }} {{ (member | async)?.lastName }}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox color="positive" [(ngModel)]="member.checked" (click)="toggleClicked(member, !member.checked)" item-right></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

When calling the `toggleClicked` function when the `ion-checkbox` is clicked, the first parameter I want to pass in is the member's key and not the full member *(as is shown)*. This is described in the [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#meta-fields-on-the-object) in the docs as just using `member.$key` but that returns `undefined`.

I can display the key again by using the `async` pipe using:
`(member | async).$key`

However, I cannot do this within an arguments listings as you can't have pipes there.

**EDIT:**

`_tripMembers` is just a basic JS array that holds `FirebaseObjectObservable`'s. Since a `member` is an individual item in firebase I would have thought it would be a `FirebaseObjectObservable` and NOT a `FirebaseListObservable`. The example in the documentation is that if you are getting a **LIST** of items, you use a `FirebaseListObservable`. You would use a `FirebaseObjectObservable` if you are only getting individual items *(which is what I'm doing)*,

```
getUserWithID(userID): FirebaseObjectObservable<any> {
    return this.af.database.object('users/' + userID);
}

setTripMembers(): void {
    allUsers.forEach((user) => {
        tripMembersID.forEach((member) => {
            if (user.$key === member) {
                tripMembers.push(getUserWithID(user.$key));
            }
        });
    });


    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(LocationModal, {
        name: name,
        members: tripMembers
    });
}
```

Is this wrong? Should getting an individual item be a `FirebaseListObservable`? If yes, can someone then please explain as in what scenario we a `FirebaseObjectObservable` would be used as I don't feel the docs explain it well.

Or is it that `_tripMembers` has to be a `FirebaseListObservable<FirebaseObjectObservable>`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use async everywhere. Just use it in the ngFor on your collection.

`<ion-list *ngFor="let member of _tripMembers | async">`

**EDIT:**

You'll want to "unwrap" the observables on the code side before they make it to your template, and without passing them around or pushing them into your array.

[Take a look at this comment which helped me out when starting with AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/380#issuecomment-234666818).

`this.af.database.object('path')` is meant to be consumed & automagically unwrapped by the template. To get the data out of it on the code side requires you to subscribe to it. But just subscribing will leave the observable in a live state. Use the `take` operator to get the data and close the observable.

`FirebaseObjectObservable` & `FirebaseListObservable` are simple ways to get your data showing up in a template. But once you start manipulating them you need to do more work with the Observables to create POJOs/Arrays which will end up as the model for your views.

It might end up looking something like:

```
let membersArray = [];

// your forEach

this.af.database.object(`path/to/${member}`)
.take(1)
.subscribe(member => {
  console.log(`member`, member);
  membersArray.push(member);
});

// end of forEach
```

Comment: That throws the following error `Error: Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`. `_tripMembers` is an `Array<any>` if you wanted to know

Comment: I didn't read intently enough to notice you were using `FirebaseObjectObservable` instead of `FirebaseListObservable`, which it should be assuming `_tripMembers` is an array rather than an object.

Comment: But shouldn't `_tripMembers` be an Array of `FirebaseObjectObservable`'s? I thought it would be an object seeing as each `member` is an individual item in firebase. I.e. a member is a user NOT a list of users

Comment: So in this example: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#retrieve-data, a `FirebaseListObservable` is used as it's getting a list of `items` and not individual ones

Comment: Yes, that example is what you're going for. I don't think you'd ever iterate over an object with `*ngFor`.

Comment: I will edit my question to provide more clarity to what I'm doing